# What tools should I use to build data visualization dashboard

Tags: maps, data-visualization, data-analysis

I needed help and guidance on something. I had developed a web form that would require users to submit their planting information about the crop planted, location, date of planting, planting technique, level of experience etc. This information is what I am going to use to develop planting calendars so that it will answer questions like when should i plant this crop? This information will be displayed in terms of interactive charts, graphs and plots and also maps and dashboard to filter data. Like for instance a chart should be drawn if a user selects/filters out crop planted and their location in the dashboard, I should have the charts/graphs/plots of date planted, planting technique and experience. I would also select a crop and a specific year and I should get a line plot showing extents of it throughout that year. I was thinking of making it a web map and chart. However, I was not sure of the best open source tools that will set this to work. I had an idea that should connect maybe the maps and the charts and graphs together such that what i filter out in the dashboard, say I select California as the location and the date range, I should have the map zoom to that location while plotting graduated symbols of the crops and at the same time drawing out charts and graphs of the crops lets say outside the map, in a section of its own.

If anyone of you has an idea of some of the best tools I can use to set this to work, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana could probably satisfy your needs. Besides its core data analytics functionality with support for building all kinds of tables/charts/graphs, it also has plugins for handling geographical data on maps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Let me have a look at it if it is open-source, I however wanted to build it from my coding skills.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting use case. While there are dozens of data visualization tools (DVTs) available; but will recommend the following options-

1. Tableau
2. Grafana
3. Google Analytics

[Take a look at some differences between commonly used DVTs.](https://techieatom.com/data-visualization-tools-grafana-kibana-tableau/)